# Able to use widget but not plot in the same function (bokeh)

Tags: python, data-visualization, bokeh

The code is divided into two classes - `table` and `representation.`I am using bokeh for plotting.

When I click on a widget, it creates a class `table` and takes me to object `representation.get_dia(),`which should give me a line and a paragraph.

Code snippet from the `table`

```
def update_on_button_click():
            print(final_data)
            rep=representation(final_data)
            rep.get_dia()
```

`get_dia()` function -

```
def get_dia(self):
            curdoc().clear()
            from bokeh.models import Paragraph
            p2 = Paragraph(text='Under Construction',width=200, height=100)
            p1=figure()
            p1.line([1,2,3],[1,2,3])
            curdoc().add_root(row(p2,p1))
```

The function displays the paragraph in the browser but not the plot.

Is there any reason why this happens?

P.S The plot is visible, if I call it from the `table` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#from bokeh.plotting import figure --- adding this (even though I had added 
#this at the starting itself)
def get_dia(self):
        #curdoc().clear() --- And Removing this  solves the problem
        from bokeh.models import Paragraph 
        p2 = Paragraph(text='Under Construction',width=200, height=100)
        p1=figure()
        p1.line([1,2,3],[1,2,3])
        curdoc().add_root(row(p2,p1))
```